# Show that if $f$,$g$ are iso arrows, then $f\circ g$ is too.

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory

Could anyone check my proof please?

> Show that if $f$, $g$ are iso arrows, then $f\circ g$ is too, with $(f\circ g)^{-1}=g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$.

R Goldbatt's *Topoi*: $f:a\to b$ is an iso arrow (or invertible) if there is an arrow $g: b\to a$ such that $g\circ f=1_a$ ($1_a$ being the identity arrow on $a$) and $f\circ g=1_b$.

So let's assume that $g: a\to b$ and $f: b\to c$ (I know it's confusing, but the other way round seems even more so...), then the task is to find an arrow $h: c\to a$ such that $h\circ f\circ g=1_a$ and $f\circ g\circ h=1_c$.

It would seem that $f\circ g^{-1}$ is a good candiate for $h$. So I need to show that $(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})\circ (f \circ g)=1_a$.

Let's beging with $(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})\circ (f \circ g)(a)$. But because $f$ is iso, let $f^{-1}$ be that inverting arrow:

$(g^{-1}\circ 1_b) \circ g(a)$. But composing with identity just gives you the function, so we can take $1_b$ out here, i.e.

$g^{-1}\circ g(a)$; but since $g$ is also iso we apply the same trick so we end up with $1_a(a)$.

$f\circ g\circ h=1_c$ should be able to be proved in a similar manner.

Comment: "...it's confusing..." It is a pity more people don't move over to Martin Isaac's convention: write $f(x)$ and $(x)f$ interchangeably, but stiick to $fg$ for first $f$, then $g$. It makes life much simpler. Out of curiosity, what level is the course you are doing (eg 2nd yr undergrad, grad school)?

Comment: @almagest Haha ok, now I am getting confused about that convention. This is a Master's level course, although it's with the logic program at our philosophy dept instead of maths. I have absolutely no maths background though so hence my insecurity about my proof.

Comment: Interesting. When I was young, most mathematicians were sceptical about category theory. It was taught as an unpopular grad school course. Now it seems to pop up in all kinds of places outside maths. I hadn't realised philosphers had got interested!

Comment: It seems perfectly correct to me, exactly as you wrote it. (I intensely dislike saying critical things here, but I don’t think the first comment of @almagest was likely to be at all helpful to you.)

Comment: @Lubin There is definitely some things off about the presentation, see my answer. I do agree that the idea of the proof is correct.

Comment: @almagest Even though we can argue that that would have been a better convention, fact is we are stuck with writing $fg$ for "$f$ after $g$". So I would not advice starting to use some nonstandard convention and just get used to what is used everywhere. As a small tip: for me it really helped to start reading the $\circ$ symbol as "after", so $f \circ g$ would literally read as "$f$ after $g$", which leaves very little room for confusion.

Comment: @MarkKamsma The whole point of category theory is to make a lot of basic things transparent, so you don't have to think about them and can focus on the difficult things. Having a stupid convention does not help. It is particularly stupid in category theory, because as you point out in your excellent answer below, category theory is trying to get away from focussing on elements in the objects, We are fpcussing on the arrows instead. We never need $f(a)$,

Comment: @almagest The point is that in most of the literature (books and articles, even on category theory) the convention is that $fg$ means "$f$ after $g$". So I would never advice someone to learn doing it the other way around, *especially* if the current convention confuses them. Otherwise it will only become harder to read those books and articles, and others will be confused by whatever you write yourself.

Comment: @MarkKamsma You were correct in an earlier comment. (1) we are unlikely to agree on this topic. (2) here is not an ideal place to debate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you got the right idea to use the inverses of $f$ and $g$ to create an inverse for $f \circ g$. The essence of the proof is also there, but there are a few issues with the presentation that would really make the proof harder to read for someone who doesn't know how it would go on beforehand.

First you say $f \circ g^{-1}$ is a good candidate, but I would read this as $f \circ (g^{-1})$, which would definitely not work and is also not what you use. It would not even compose, since $g^{-1}: b \to a$ and $f: b \to c$. If you mean $(f \circ g)^{-1}$, then you get into a circular argument. You are currently trying to show that the inverse of $f \circ g$, which we denote by $(f \circ g)^{-1}$, exists.

Luckily you continue working with $g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}$, which does exist by the assumption of $f$ and $g$ being isomorphisms. This will indeed be the inverse of $f \circ g$. Then you want to show that $g^{-1} \circ f^{-1} \circ f \circ g = 1_a$ (tip, you can omit the parentheses because composition is associative). The key idea is there, namely:
$$
g^{-1} \circ f^{-1} \circ f \circ g =
g^{-1} \circ 1_b \circ g =
g^{-1} \circ g =
1_a.
$$
However, you write "$(a)$" after all these things, as if you are applying a function to some element $a$. This is not correct, arrows in a category are not necessarily functions of sets. So you cannot apply them to elements. The way to reason is often very similar though. The thing I just wrote here is really the same as what you wrote, just without the "$(a)$" bits.

So long story short: good insights, the spirit of the proof is correct, just some issues with the presentation. I would say you are on the right track of learning this stuff!

Comment: @MarkKamsmaThank you very much for the detailed answer and suggestions on presentation! I really need to stop the $f(a)$ thing since you actually reminded me on an earlier question as well haha

Comment: @DanielMak That is actually quite a common mistake, so I did not realise that was you! Good to see you remember the feedback :) And happy to help of course.